# Unittest and mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm testing with `unittest` in Python and it's ok. Now, I have introduced `mock` and I need to resolve a question. This is my code:

```
from mock import Mock
import unittest


class Matematica(object):
    def __init__(self, op1, op2):
        self.op1 = op1
        self.op2 = op2
    def adder(self):
        return self.op1 + self.op2
    def subs(self):
        return abs(self.op1 - self.op2)
    def molt(self):
        return self.op1 * self.op2
    def divid(self):
        return self.op1 / self.op2

class TestMatematica(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test della classe Matematica"""
    def testing(self):
        """Somma"""
        mat = Matematica(10,20)
        self.assertEqual(mat.adder(),30)
        """Sottrazione"""
        self.assertEqual(mat.subs(),10)

class test_mock(object):
    def __init__(self, matematica):
        self.matematica = matematica
    def execute(self):
        self.matematica.adder()
        self.matematica.adder()
        self.matematica.subs()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(TestMatematica('testing'))
    a = Matematica(10,20)    
    b = test_mock(a)
    b.execute()
    mock_foo = Mock(b.execute)#return_value = 'rafa')
    mock_foo()
    print mock_foo.called
    print mock_foo.call_count
    print mock_foo.method_calls
```

This code is functionally and result of `print` is: `True`, `1`, `[]`. Now, I need to count how many times are called `self.matematica.adder()` and `self.matematica.subs()`.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I want to know: count how many times are called self.matematica.adder() and self.matematica.subs().

Answer (score 1):

you could just run again your code but the second time with a MagicMock object.

```
from mock import Mock
from mock import MagicMock  # import MagicMock
from collections import Counter
import unittest


class Matematica(object):
    def __init__(self, op1, op2):
        self.op1 = op1
        self.op2 = op2
    def adder(self):
        return self.op1 + self.op2
    def subs(self):
        return abs(self.op1 - self.op2)
    def molt(self):
        return self.op1 * self.op2
    def divid(self):
        return self.op1 / self.op2

class TestMatematica(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test della classe Matematica"""
    def testing(self):
        """Somma"""
        mat = Matematica(10,20)
        self.assertEqual(mat.adder(),30)
        """Sottrazione"""
        self.assertEqual(mat.subs(),10)

class test_mock(object):
    def __init__(self, matematica):
        self.matematica = matematica
    def execute(self):
        self.matematica.adder()
        self.matematica.adder()
        self.matematica.subs()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(TestMatematica('testing'))
    a = Matematica(10,20)    
    b = test_mock(a)
    b.execute()
    mock_foo = Mock(b.execute)#return_value = 'rafa')
    mock_foo()
    print mock_foo.called
    print mock_foo.call_count
    print mock_foo.method_calls

    # added from here
    c = MagicMock()
    d = test_mock(c)
    d.execute()
    method_count = Counter([str(method) for method in c.method_calls])
    print c.method_calls
    print method_count
```

Results are:

```
OK
True
1
[]
[call.adder(), call.adder(), call.subs()]
Counter({'call.adder()': 2, 'call.subs()': 1})
```

There it is, method_count contains now how many times each method was called.

Regards

Comment: Sorry, another question. If in my code, for example, the matematica.adder has parameters adder(a,b), how I can know the value of a and b that I pass? THANKS

Comment: You will have to mock your adder() method so you can keep track of the arguments passed to the function. Mock defines a [call_args](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) and a [call_args_list](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) attributes where you can access it.